# Leave placeholder text while focused

Tags: jquery, html

I know this is probably a bit of a stretch, and I'll probably have to end up using some sort of javascript, but I would like to know if this is possible.

Is it possible have the HTML5 placeholder text remain visible while the text field has focus?  In Webkit browsers, this is default, but in Firefox the text is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's firefox's default behavior for placeholder. It is not possible till now.